# Google Cloud Instance External Ip not responding /

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My Instance was working fine with domain and everything but then i made a change in php.ini to upload file size and restarted the instance. Since then i am not able to access my site. I am able to ping to external ip from commandline but when i try to visit the domain or the ip I get the error .

This site can’t be reached . site.com took too long to respond.

Whats strange is that when i access site.com/anyrandomstring . I get page not found error 404, just html no css or anything else loaded. These are my firewall configs.

default-allow-http
http-server 
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:80
Allow
1000
default

default-allow-https
https-server
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:443 
Allow
1000
default

wordpress-1-tcp-443
wordpress-1-tcp-443 
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:443 
Allow
1000
default

wordpress-1-tcp-80
wordpress-1-tcp-80
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:80
Allow
1000
default

default-allow-icmp
Apply to all
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
icmp
Allow
65534
default

default-allow-internal
Apply to all
IP ranges: 10.128.0.0/9
tcp:0-65535, udp:0-65535, 1 more
Allow
65534
default

default-allow-rdp
Apply to all
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:3389
Allow
65534
default

default-allow-ssh
Apply to all
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:22
Allow
65534
default

Any idea what is the issue? I have a wordpress website running on that installation.